# Difference between iPhone native app with webkit and PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cordova, webkit

When utilizing PhoneGap vs. an Objective-C based iPhone app (i.e. native app) making `webview` calls that load html/js/css content, what are the key differences?

Does PhoneGap make `uiwebview`?  From my understanding of PhoneGap, it does but I am looking for clarification.

Ultimately, I would like to build a *hybrid* iPhone application, utilizing *both* Objective-C and html/js/css? An appealing approach is to utilize Objective-C to communicate with a server in the background and utilize html/js/css to build the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key difference between a PhoneGap app vs an Objective-C based application making `webview` calls is the library of javscript functions PhoneGap offers to utilize native functionality *without* needing to write native Objective-C code.

You are absolutely correct that PhoneGap utilizes the `UIWebView` class within the iOS library  but keep in mind the appeal of PhoneGap is the ability to utilize a *single code base* on *multiple platforms*.

Hybrid Objective-C and html/js/css applications are indeed possible with PhoneGap.  If you check out what PhoneGap generates for the iOS platform, it is simply a template application with plenty of Objective-C and you simply need to make a flow that achieves the desired structure of your application.

Keep in mind though, the biggest appeal to PhoneGap is the ability to build cross platform apps with a single code base.  Everything you write in Objective-C will need to be written again if you wish to launch on Android or WindowsPhone.

#### Other Notes

You may also want to check out [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), it a really great mobile web framework that works well with PhoneGap.  There is a chapter in *[Master Mobile Web Apps with jQuery Mobile](http://store.elated.com/)* that outlines this fairly well.